# Product of Friedel-Crafts cyclisation of (3-methylpent-4-en-1-yl)benzene

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, aromatic-compounds, carbocation

My proposed mechanism and final product is:

[image: Mechanism and proposed product]

But the book says the answer is:

[image: 1-ethyl-1-methyl-2,3-dihydro-1H-indene]

I know that a 6 membered ring is more stable than a 5 membered ring so I made the product with the 6 membered ring (however, the carbocation was a secondary carbocation).

However, the book claims the answer to be the one with the 5 membered ring (the carbocation here was a tertiary carbocation).

Is the answer provided in the book wrong?

Comment: Then I suppose the carbocation thus formed rearranges to 3° and then is being attacked by benzene. Later through electrophilic substitution the product given in the book is obtained.

Comment: Related: [Why are 7-membered rings less likely to form than 5- and 6- membered rings?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/48622/why-are-7-membered-rings-less-likely-to-form-than-5-and-6-membered-rings)

Comment: The comments seem to underestimate the fact that a tertiary carbocation is more favorable due to inductive effect. So, then it will form pentacarbon ring on the second step. And I don't think there is much strain in a pentacarbon ring.

Comment: I think the carbocation will rearrange to a more stable one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Though the question is old and pretty much answered in the comments, I ran into this question and draw the mechanism, so I thought about summarizing all that was brought up in an answer.

The carbocation is first formed on the secondary carbon. However, molecules are more stable when the charges are delocalized ([this page](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Organic_Chemistry/Map%3A_Organic_Chemistry_(McMurry)/Chapter_07%3A_Alkenes%3A_Structure_and_Reactivity/7.09_Carbocation_Structure_and_Stability) talks about the stability of carbocations). When the positive charge is in the secondary carbon, it can only "share the burden" of having this charge with 2 neighbor carbons. So the tertiary carbon donates an hydrogen through a *sigma to atomic* orbital interaction (the *sp3* hybdrization allows a π-type interaction) resulting in the more stable tertiary carbocation seen in the mechanism below:

[image: Mechanism]

Then the reaction follows analogously to the pathway you deduced for the 6 membered ring: First a *π to atomic* orbital interaction between the aromatic ring and the tertiary carbocation, which I believe to be the Rate Determining Step since it breaks the ring aromacity (bigger energy gap). Then finally the *sigma to atomic* interaction between the hydrogen and the ring carbocation, that restores aromaticity and releases the hydrogen.