# Bromination of but-3-en-1-ol in basic medium and Baldwin's rules

Tags: reaction-mechanism, nucleophilic-substitution

> [image]

After formation of the bromocarbocation the alkoxide anion attacks the bromocarbocation which leads to ring formation and can proceed through two pathways [image]

5 endo tet cyclization is disfavored but 4 exo tet cyclization is favored according to Baldwin's rules; however, the answer given in my text book is the 5 membered ring.

Answer (score 4):

Your reasoning is totally correct according to Baldwin's Rule - the 4-exo-product would be more stable than the 5-endo-product ( see : [This](http://www.reading.ac.uk/acadepts/sd/pharmacy/public_html/staff/andre/BaldwinsRules-RAJ.pdf) for more details).

But your method may be wrong in the given question the product A was first formed and then a ring closure step was performed using $\ce{KOH}$ as shown below :
[image]
[image]

here the 5-exo-trig ring closure is favoured according to Baldwin's rule .

Let me also address something that may be a doubt ( It was mine ) i.e. why doesn't the oxygen atom attack the bromonium Ion in the first step ? this is because even if it will attack you will also form a acid $\ce{HBr}$ which will cause the cleavage in the cyclic ester we just formed returning us to the original reagent hence it doesn't attack.

Comment: Upon closer reading, I do want to point out some inaccuracies. (1) Baldwin's rules do not say anything about the *stability of products*, but only whether the route for their formation is *kinetically* possible. The 4-*exo*-*tet* pathway is "favoured", and the 5-*endo*-*tet* is "disfavoured". Of course, it does so happen that the five-membered ring is more stable than the four-membered ring. That, however, is not a consequence of Baldwin's rules. (2) Also, there are no *trig* ring closures; SN2 takes place at a *tet*rahedral carbon, hence *tet*.

Comment: (3) Finally, and maybe more critically: in the SN2 step, both possibilities - 4-*exo*-*tet*, as well as 5-*exo*-*tet* - are "favoured", according to Baldwin's rules. Therefore, invoking Baldwin's rules is not sufficient to explain which pathway is *preferred*, as the rules do not distinguish between which is "more favoured". The preference for 5-membered ring formation over 4-membered ring formation is explained by the balance between enthalpy and entropy of activation, see https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/107070/16683 as well as pp 805–807 in Clayden 2nd ed