# X - membered rings in formation of epoxide

Tags: organic-chemistry

https://youtu.be/d4RczD122QI?t=2025

In this lecture, I am learning to form epoxides from the intramolecular version of Williamson Ether synthesis. During that, the professor says the ring formation is favored when ring is 3/5/6-membered, and not favored in 4/>6-membered. I tried to think of: smaller bond angle increases ring strain, but this does not explain why 3-membered ring is favored.

I checked the answer to this question.

[Why are 7-membered rings less likely to form than 5- and 6- membered rings?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/48622/why-are-7-membered-rings-less-likely-to-form-than-5-and-6-membered-rings)

1. It seems that 3-membered rings have a very positive ΔG, how come it is favorable?
2. In the last graph of the answer, overall rate of formation of 4 & 6-membered rings seems around the same (log k(intra)), which I really want to know the explanation of that. In general, what membered rings are actually favored?

Comment: That answer explains why three-membered rings are formed easily; it's because of the entropy factor.

Comment: Pretty much the same issue is discussed here: [Dependence of rates of neighbouring group participation on length of alkyl chain](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/107027/16683)